# Why don't we get 0=0 when we take limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose a function $f(x)= x^2$

Then $\Delta f(x)= 2x\Delta x +(\Delta x)^2$
And in the limit $df=2xdx$
Now the problem that I have is that after taking the limit shouldn't we get $0=0$ as $df$ and $dx$ both approach zero?

Comment: While I'm not fond of your notation, why do you worry about $0 = 0$? Do you not believe that $0 = 0$ is true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Taking the limit of what as what goes to what? I would guess that you'd be taking the limit of each side of $\Delta f(x) = 2x \Delta x + (\Delta x)^2$ as $\Delta x \to 0$, in which case you do indeed get $0 = 0$. Am I missing something from your question?

Comment: My question is that why do we stop at $df=2xdx$ after taking the limits, shouldn't taking the limit lead us to 0=0 directly?

Comment: @TheoBandit This is a typical "physicist" calculus argument. It makes complete sense in that context (they do this kind of stuff all the time and the correct answer does pop out at the other end), but finding the mathematical rigor behind it will take some work. That's what this question is asking for, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The meaningful way to interpret the statement $\mathrm df=2x\,\mathrm dx$ is not that $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}(\Delta f(x)-2x\Delta x)=0,$$ which as you say is trivially true, but that $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta f(x)}{2x\Delta x}=1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So writing it the other way is just an abuse of notation?

Comment: Also before integrating we do write it in the first way, is that incorrect? I understand that it has to be interpreted the other way but is writing it the first way incorrect or does it mean something else?

Comment: @AkshatSharma: Yes it **is indeed** abuse of notation. It's like saying $n^2 = (n+1)^2$ as $n → ∞$. Utterly wrong, and the instance in your question is just as bad.